# MSSSQL: SSRS, SSAS, SSIS edition

Tags: ssrs, ssis, sql-server

How can I know which edition of SSRS, SSAS and SSIS service is installed on a server?
Finding database edition is easy but how to find edition for other SQL services?

Any help please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out edition of SSRS, go to:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\Log on the server which has SSRS

Open the Summary.txt file.
Look for the log file for Product : Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services.

In the SSRS log file, search for keyword "edition"